# Create ZIP archive containing Windows junctions?

Tags: compression, zip

I have a folder containing normal files and directories but also Windows junctions.

When I try to zip the folder I get an error that some files cannot be read.

These files are Windows junctions.

Is it possible to create a ZIP archive supporting junctions?

Or is there another archive format supporting junctions?

Comment: It doesn't make sense to include a NTFS junction as a junction in an archive as the target system will have different identifiers. There are formats that support soft links. What did you use to create the archvie?

Comment: Junctions are not soft links. There are 3 types of links in Windows (hard links, soft links and junctions). I tried both WinRar and 7zip. There are archives supporting soft links. But none is supporting junctions

Comment: I know about the difference but functionally you could replace a junctions by a soft link in a lot of cases and in comparison to junctions soft links are portable. Best you could do if you really need junctions is to use a WIM and DISM [see here](https://superuser.com/questions/1370260/7zip-force-ignore-ntfs-junctions) for an example.